# Como fazer uma verificação em um arquivo do linux baseado no tempo de criação?

Tags: linux, bash

estou montando um script de backup e  preciso criar uma verificação para analisar se algum arquivo em uma pasta foi criado nos últimos 7 dias, qual o caminho para isso? Eu sei que o comando `ls -lt` lista os arquivos na ordem de ultima criação ou alteração e mostra o mês, dia, hora e minuto, como posso usar essas informação?

Comment: Dependendo do que está fazendo, dá uma olhada no logrotate , pode ser útil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find /home/pasta_alvo -type f -mtime +7
```

1 - `find /home/pasta_alvo -type f` (para localizar os arquivos)

2 - `-mtime +7` (7 dias da sua criação)

Caso queira, pode apagar esses arquivos:

```
find /home/pasta_alvo -type f -mtime +7 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

- `-ctime` = criado
- `-mtime` = modificado
- `-atime` = acessado

Espero que seja útil.